# local_path not showing in rviz while robot navigates

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, navfn, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

I'm trying to show the local path when my robot is navigating, but the path only shows for about 1/4 of a second, disappears for about 10 seconds, then repeats.

I know I am subscribing to the right topic because, like I said, I can see the local path. But why is it behaving that way?
Any parameters I need to update (maybe through dynamic configuration while the robot runs), or is there a more appropriate topic I shall subscribe to?

The global path shows up fine, and it stays until the robot reaches the goal point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203800/local_path-not-showing-in-rviz-while-robot-navigates/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure, you can try looking at the path being published using `rostopic echo <topic_name>` and see if there is anything fishy going on. The only thing I could think of is that zero length paths are being published on the same topic (maybe multiple nodes are publishing to the same topic). You could also do `rostopic info <topic_name>` to make sure only one process is publishing to it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-02-26**:
The teleop/joystick node does not seem to be publishing, so I did not see any conflict. I still can't figure out what is going on. I'll also make sure that the robot is not actually latching to the last command that teleop sent it.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-04-05**:
Any updates on debugging this?